# TypeError, When calculating variables from a dictionary

Tags: python, types, dictionary

What Type is a `val_dict.get(filename)[1]`? I keep getting this Typeerror, telling me its a NoneType:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

When I try to run a script with this line :

```
water = (float(x1[count]) * (val_dict.get(filename[1]))
```

I keep getting the errors. I've tried calling a `float`, `int` and `str`, but it obviously didn't help.

I've written a script to import certain values from an Excel-spreadsheet and scale them. After that my script is supposed to extract these values to a new excel spreadsheet, and what I thought was the easiest way was storing all my data in a dictionary that looks like this:

```
        val_dict[filename] = [model, lenghtvalue, dispvalue, Froudemax, Froudemin]

return val_dict

val_dict = locate_vals()
print val_dict
#output:
{'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\Test spreadsheet model 151B WL3.xls': [u'M151B', 14.89128, 316.29, 1.0, 0.4041900066850382], 'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\FolderA\\Test spreadsheet model 151 WL1 Lastet.xls': [u'M151', 14.672460000000001, 316.28887, 1.0, 0.4041900066850382]}
```

In case it is interesting, the x1-list's output looks like this:

```
[0.35714285714285715, 0.35714285714285715] [1.5845602477694463e-07, 1.5845602477694463e-07]
```

Comment: It implies that val_dict does not have the key filename[1]. Can you print filename[1] and see if it's correct?

Comment: @lazy functor:
`for filename in val_dict:
    print val_dict.get(filename)[1]`
#output:
`14.89128
14.67246`

#while
`for filename in val_dict:
    print filename[1]`
#gives the following output:`
`:
:`

Comment: Oh! Just realized it! I forgot a ')' after filename!
I've included it elsewhere in my script, but forgot it in that single line. Thanks @lazy functor !

Comment: Just a little bit late to my answer there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
water = (float(x1[count]) * (val_dict.get(filename[1]))
```

Which should be:

```
water = (float(x1[count]) * (val_dict.get(filename)[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! 
Just realized it after Lazy Functor's post, but thank you for answering anyways. Been stuck because of that `)` for a while :p

Answer (score 1):

`val_dict[filename]` is an array which can be indexed, however `filename` is not.

P.S. 
I think the following picture might help (from the blog post [*29 common beginner Python errors on one page*](http://pythonforbiologists.com/index.php/29-common-beginner-python-errors-on-one-page/)).

[image: 29 common beginner Python errors on one page]